# Sending Data to a Specific Android Device

Tags: android, communication

I am planning an application that includes a membership card functionality, where the user can place an order, either in the application or by phoning the vendor.  Once the order is placed, especially in the case of a phone in order, what would be the best approach to having the vendor side communicate relevant details to a specific device.

I have looked Android's C2DM, that doesn't seem to be the best method.  I don't want to send messages/data to all devices with the application installed, only the specific device that placed the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) is **device specific**. So in your case, when user `X` initiates a phone order, your back-end could quite easily send the relevant data back to `X`'s device (assuming you've verified that the person calling in is indeed`X`).

This data **would not** be broadcast to everyone who installed your app.